# Image Enhancement through Wavelet Decomposition

Tags: opencv, image-processing, wavelet-transform, image-enhancement, pywt

I am trying to use Region based Histogram Equalization on 'Approximation Coefficients' generated from Wavelet Decomposition.

Here is the code:-

loading image

```
img = cv2.imread("some_image.jpg")
```

discrete wavelet transform - cA Approx Coeff; cD Detail Coeff

```
cA, cD = pywt.dwt(img, 'db2')
```

Applying CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization) on cA - Approx Coeff

```
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
clahe.apply(cA)
```

I want to apply Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization on 'cA'(Approx Coeff) however python throws an error. Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

```
error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\clahe.cpp:360: error: (-215) _src.type() == CV_8UC1 || _src.type() == CV_16UC1 in function `anonymous-namespace'::CLAHE_Impl::apply
```

UPDATE:
I am trying to accomplish the Approx Coefficients-> REgion based histogram enhancement section of the diagram. 
[Block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTd6c.png)

Comment: basically it tells you that it accepts an 8bit greyscale image (1 channel) or 16 bit image (also 1 channel). OpenCV loads by default RGB images (even if it is a greyscale one). You can add another parameter (cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) to the imread function (2nd position) to load the image as a greyscale

Comment: I have updated the post with a link to the block diagram I am working on. For some reason CLAHE does not accept 'cA' as a proper input source.

Comment: print the shape of cA and it's type

Comment: shape: (720, 1280, 3)

type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: the last ,3 tells you that it is a BGR (or any other 3 channel image) image and it should be 1 channel

Comment: The last 3 is indicative of the type of Wavelet Daubechies (db) you use.
db1 gives rise to (720,1280,2)
db2 gives rise to (720,1280,3)

Comment: The last three is NOT related to the number of channels but rather the type of wavelet decomposition one chooses.

Comment: well, in OpenCV it they want it to be 1 as the documentation says, I do not doubt your work, just I am telling you what OpenCV is expecting as input type.... to make it work it has to be "1 channel" or in other words 2 dimensional image like structure...